# How to specify test tags correctly in dart_test.yaml?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a dart project that has several tests, when I try to run an isolated test I get this warning:

Warning: A tag was used that wasn't specified in dart_test.yaml.
"tagName" was used in the suite itself

how should i declare these tags correctly in dart_test.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Steps

1. Create a file `dart_test.yaml` at the root of your project
2. Add your tags one after another under a `tags` field
3. Add tags to your `test` or `testWidget` declaration
4. Run your tests with the `-t` flag followed by the wanted tag

### Sample

Let's say I want to add the following tags: golden, atom, molecule, organism, mobile, desktop. My `dart_test.yaml` will look like this:

```yaml
tags:
  golden:
  atom:
  molecule:
  organism:
  mobile:
  desktop:
```

And everything should be okay you can write your test:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'this is a test',
    (tester) async {
      // ...
    },
    tags: ['atom', 'mobile'],
  );
}
```

You can run it with the following command:

```bash
$ flutter test -t mobile
```

[source](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/pkgs/test/doc/configuration.md#configuring-tags)

Comment: I tried this before when i read the documentation but my lint gives me an [error](https://postimg.cc/64cV3SQN),

Comment: I have the same but you can ignore it.

Comment: @Leneak You can append an empty object to the tags, for example, `golden: {}`.